# Time tracking in TFS using VS2013

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, tfs, time-tracking

I am using Team Foundation Server to track my projects and tasks (I'm using the MSF for CMMI process template), so in Visual Studio 2013 I can start a task, but I have not found a way to track the time spent on the task; the fields **Remaining work** and **Completed work** stay empty.

I found the tool **[tfsworkingon](https://tfsworkingon.codeplex.com/)**  that does this function, and other tools for TFS, but I was searching for a way to do this natively within Visual Studio. Does anyone know if VS2013 has this behavior natively and how I can use this?

https://tfsworkingon.codeplex.com/documentation

Comment: TFS has never been a time-tracking tool. The closest you can come is the "My Work" feature in Visual Studio 2013, but even _that_ doesn't run a timer or anything.

Comment: In fact, when you think about it, an automatic timer makes no sense. Do you count time spent in the rest room? Do you want to have TFS stop tracking time spent by a colleague talking to you about some other project? It's necessary for a human to figure out how much time is spent - TFS will then gladly record what the human counts.

Comment: but the objective is count the real time spent working in the task, for in the future know how much time i need to complete a similar task

Comment: But TFS can't _know_ the real time in the task. A human has to tell it.

Comment: but to control the time i will use tfsworkingon, for start/stop the work in the task, replacing human labor, avoiding errors on count.

Comment: Sorry, but TFS has never had such functionality, and I doubt that it ever will. Most people don't work well that way.

Comment: this functionality isnt TFS native, look here https://tfsworkingon.codeplex.com/documentation

Comment: Kind of surprised that so many people are poo-pooing the idea of time tracking.  FogBugz does this about as well as can be expected.  TFS should add a feature to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think there is anything out of the box in Tfs that allows you to automatically tracked time.

I worked in a project where we used the Pomodoro technique to track time spent. The entire team used Pomorodo sequences of 20 minutes and we added a custom field for capture the number of Pomodoro sequences for each task - both actual and estimated.

The tool we used to track time was [Pomodairo](https://code.google.com/p/pomodairo/), which was outside our development environment. I see that there is a [Visual Studio extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/de64d8bf-be88-4592-a7da-39fe2b64d90d) available as well but I haven't used it personally.

Answer (score 0):

If you are searching for a tool to track your efforts in Visual Studio/TFS, maybe you want to take a look at http://www.tfs-timetracker.com. We have developed this tool for tracking directly on TFS workitems, fully integrated into Team Foundation Server. Based on the idea to help developers learn about their speed and where their time is really going, we focus on tracking. So you have for instance a client that is acting like a stopwatch, you can start/stop while you work (amongst other ways to track). Maybe this helps.

Answer (score -1):

### Sort answer: *No TFS and Visual Studio don't offer a native way to keep track of your time for you*.

### Long answer:

Remaining work and Completed work are both to be filled by the team members working on the item. Remaining work is an estimate of the currently remaining time (and it can go up if you've found more work to be done), completed work is the amount of time spent so far.

Since Visual Studio doesn't know what you do all the time, you could be reading email, checking facebook, having a chat at the coffee machine, etc it won't track the Completed work for you. Since Visual Studio can't predict the future it can't re-estimate the Remaining work either.

The general guidance is to not use TFS for time tracking. It can be used to track some aspects of time, but these features doesn't handle good coding practices like pair programming without creating way to many duplicate tasks. It also re-enforces the idea of individual ownership over collective ownership and assumes that we can predict teh future accurately when we assign the Remaining Work value.

If you need to track your time spent, the advice is to track it at a higher level (Requirement or Change Request for CMMI or even better, at the Feature level).

3rd party plugins for TFS offer time tracking features including start/stop timer options.